# Definition of an oriented graph

Tags: graph-theory

I found that one calls: An oriented graph $G$ is a triple $G = (V, E, i)$, where $V$ is a finite
set $V = \{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ whose elements are called vertex and $E$ is a finite set whose
elements are called edges and a map $i: E \rightarrow V \times V$ with $i(e) = \{e^−, e^+\}$, where $e^−$ is the origin of the edge $e$ and $e^+$ is the end of the edge $e$.

Actually I cannot visualize the above said definition. Can anyone please represent it  diagramatically?

Please help me to understand.

Comment: In the notation $(e^-,e^+)$ the symbols $e^-$ and $e^+$ are elements of $V$ and an oriented edge is defined as an ordered pair. That means that for an edge between (for example) $v_1$ and $v_2$ it matters which is first and which is second. For example, $(v_1,v_2)$ is the oriented edge $v_1\to v_2$ and $(v_2,v_1)$ is the oriented edge $v_2\to v_1$ distinct from $v_1\to v_2$. Compare this with the definition of an edge in a non-oriented graph where edges are defined not as ordered pairs but as sets $\{v_1,v_2\}$, so $\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $\{v_2,v_1\}$ are the same edge.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Thanks for the correction. I have edited. Actually this was a misprinting in the book which I am following.

Comment: I don't think it was a misprint. An edge in an oriented graph is defined as an ordered pair precisely because it matters which vertex is first and which is second. If there is an oriented edge $e=v\to w$, then $e^- = v$ and $e^+=w$. So instead of writing the edge $e$ with the arrow $v\to w$ we write it as an ordered pair $(v,w)$.